# Two applications bind to the same socket?

Tags: windows, port, jetty

```
C:\Users\bacadmin>netstat -anov | find ":80 "
TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 3976
TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 3808
TCP [::]:80 [::]:0 LISTENING 3976
```

The one with the process id of `3976` is a Jetty that is configured to start with `setReuseAddress(false)`. How is it possible?

Comment: Do you have ipv6 enabled? :: seems to imply it is listening on the ipv6 interface,

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Oneiroi, the **TCP [::]:80 [::]:0** is the IPv6 equivalent to the **TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:0** (which is IPv4)

Comment: But how do you explain the first two lines?

Comment: 0.0.0.0:80 means "every IP that the computer provides on port 80". So it listens on the loopback (127.0.0.1) as well as your internal network address (for example 192.168.1.1)

Comment: Yes, but it seems like there are two processes listening on the same port, isn't it?

Comment: yes that is possible to have two processes listening on the same port. If you are worried, you can kill these from Task Manager (you will need to go view and add the Process ID column in), then restart and should be fine.